# How to replace 3-byte space with 1-byte space in a CSV file?

Tags: c#, string, file, file-io, replace

I have a CSV file, and I want to replace all 3-byte spaces in each data with a 1-byte space.

Like:

```
 string str = csvData.ToString().Replace(char.ConvertFromUtf32(12288),char.ConvertFromUtf32(32))
```

How to write the code in C#?

Comment: What do you mean? Looks like valid C# code to me already...

Comment: i guess a `char` is 2 byte, so you can't replace 3 bytes with 1 byte, it's still a char, so by using char you can only replace 2 bytes by another 2 bytes. What is your exact problem? I think you are having an issue with encoding. Do you want to write the CSV as UTF8?

Comment: Note that 12288 (likely [IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE (U+3000)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm) is 2 bytes long... so it makes sample even less clear